# Which of the following statements are true about MongoDB replication?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

1. The minimum sensible number of voting nodes to a replica set is three.
2. MongoDB replication is synchronous.
3. The Mongo shell is capable of attaching to a replica set and automatically failing over.
4. By default, using the new MongoClient connection class, w=1 and j=1.
5. The oplog utilizes a capped collection.

I have selected 1,3,5 in answers but still get wrong answers.
can anyone help me which one is right options for replication?

Comment: I think I remember getting this question wrong and for some reason 3 is wrong. I think it is because when there is failover the console actually disconnects and you must redo the connection yourself as such it isn't fully automated

Comment: This is cheating but, the question is how did I get here ? ;)

Comment: I'm quite sure that the default values of W&J params were not discussed in the course - that's how I get here...

Comment: This is a Homework of the MongoDB online courses (https://education.mongodb.com/courses). You only need to see the video class to resolve it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Rather about the administration of a mongodb cluster. It should be moved to dba.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Only 1st and 5th are true.

2) MongoDB replication is **a**synchronous.

3) For mongo shell, we need to do manual fail over.

4) MongoClient connection class default write concern is w=1 and j=0.

Comment: What if you set W to the number of nodes you have and j=true? Doesn't that make the replication synchronous?

Answer (score 21):

1. Is correct, you can read more about here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/
2. Not correct. MongoDB replicattion is async.
3. Not correct. Once connected to replSet you need manually shutdown sever to cause fail over.
4. Not correct. You can read MongoClient doc here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html
   Default value's {w: 1, j:false}
5. Correct. OpLog is a capped collections.